# AuthorizationFailed for unknown principal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying an ARM template within an Azure Devops release pipeline. Amongst others, the ARM template looks up the connection string of an existing AppConfiguration instance and outputs it for use in a next step where I set the configuration of a resource.
This has worked fine for the first couple of releases. Since this week however I'm getting the following error:

```
AuthorizationFailed: The client 'adb4-etc' with object id 'adb4-etc' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/listKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/{guid}/resourcegroups/{rgname}/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/{appConfigname}' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Just to be sure the problem isn't with the ARM template, I deployed it in the Azure portal using 'Deploy a custom template' and it worked fine, outputting the connection string to the AppConfiguration. However there it used my personal user account for authentication, of course.

The pipeline uses a service connection that is connected to a principal that does not have the client ID starting with `adb4`, and there is no principal (user, app registration, enterprise application) in our Azure AD that even starts with `adb4`. So in that sense the error is correct, but why is Azure Devops authenticating with this unknown principal?

The service connection principal has the `Contributor` role on the applicable AppConfiguration instance. This access was granted weeks ago.

Comment: Double-check if you use the correct service connection, or try to create a new service connection with the service principal again, then use it. And when you check the client id in AAD, did you search it with filter `All Applications`?

Comment: @JoyWang yes, I didn't just look under Owned apps. I also tried Users and Enterprise Applications just to make sure it's really not there.
The same ARM template works fine under 2 other environments. It's just the one environment where the rights seem to be set up correctly but the pipeline uses an unknown principal.